# Why memory doesnt copy to the other memory in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, memory, copy, segment

I have problem, and I cant resolve it by myself.
I compiling my .ASM file with NASM in OMF format, and linking it to the .EXE with ALINK. It looks like:

```
C:\NASM\NASM -f obj main.asm
C:\ALINK\ALINK main.obj
```

And when I was using 09000h DOS memory to copy there my sprite memory it was works. But when I tried to use my own BSS memory to copy there my sprite memory it didnt work. My question is why? This is source code of main.asm:

```
segment stack stack
resb 64
stacktop:

section code
..start:
mov ax, data
mov ds, ax
mov ax, stack
mov ss, ax
mov sp, stacktop

; Start VGA 13h
xor ah, ah
mov al, 0013h
int 10h

; Clear buffer
mov ax, [buffer]
mov es, ax
xor di, di
mov ah, 02h
mov al, 02h
cld
mov cx, 320*200/2
rep stosw

; Copy sprite to buffer THIS NOT WORKING
push ds
mov ax, [sprite]
mov ds, ax
xor si, si
mov ax, [buffer]
mov es, ax
xor di, di
cld
mov cx, 16
rep movsw
pop ds

; Copy buffer to VGA
push ds
mov ax, [buffer]
mov ds, ax
xor si, si
mov ax, 0A000h
mov es, ax
xor di, di
cld
mov cx, 320*200/2
rep movsw
pop ds

; Wait for key
xor ah, ah
int 16h

; Start text mode
xor ah, ah
mov al, 0003h
int 10h

; Exit program (DOS)
mov ax, 4C00h
int 21h

section data
hello: db 'Hello world!', 13, 10, '$'
sprite: dw 1,1,1,1,1,1

section bss
buffer: resw 32000
```

When I replace buffer var to 09000h it works. I dont understand it.

Comment: `mov ax, [buffer]; mov es, ax` makes no sense, it loads the first 2 bytes from offset `buffer` in the data segment, and assigns that to the `es` segment. Something like `mov ax, bss; mov es, ax; lea di, [buffer]` might work better. PS: learn to use a debugger, and forget DOS.

Comment: Dude, I love DOS. Now im programming in DOS for fun, dont worry, this not to serious

Comment: The 16 bit segmented memory model is nothing but headache, see above.

Comment: It still dont work man

Comment: In the clear buffer section mov ax, [buffer]; mov es, ax working, hmm

Comment: `mov ax, [buffer]` can't "work" for any sensible definition of "work". You want a pointer to your `buffer`, which is even in a different section (which I assume is mapped to a segment) but that just loads 2 bytes from memory at offset `buffer` in the current data segment. Sounds familiar? That may just load `es` with zero though, assuming your sections are not segments (you have a `segment stack` but `section bss`, can't tell what is what)

Comment: Holy cow, man you are a god. I replace mov ax, [buffer] etc. and mov ax, [sprite] etc. with your resolve everywhere and it works

Comment: Now i change dword type of buffer to byte and change movs* and stos* instruction to bytes types and it works 100% correctly

Comment: @Jester That headache makes it a lot of fun! I'm currently writing on a C compiler for the 80286 with support for far pointers.

Comment: @fuz That's it!

Comment: @Jester Because, you know, segmentation is kind of like paging but the page size is 65536 bytes and you have to load an address in two steps.

Comment: @fuz if nostalgic, you can load 32b address in flat memory model split to 16b parts by two steps too... ;) :P (I would miss more the direct VRAM writes actually... that's why I did my last DOS+ASM project with Watcom C++ and protected mode extender, so I wrote all the initialization in C++ and then called just the 32b pure ASM for main code of app. :) Plus my data structures were already bigger than 64k at that point of time.